# Are there any public APIs with databases of historical facts?

Tags: web-services, api, resources, wikipedia

The most common source of free historical information is Wikipedia, but I am missing an API that could be used to e.g. query all things that happened on January 23rd 2010. Some iPhone apps have databases behind (www.historysurferapp.com comes to mind, but also a ton of "what happened today" apps") but they seem home-grown and/or wikipedia-based.

Anyone knows if there is such a public "timeline of everything" database somewhere?

Comment: How specific do you want to get? A timeline of *everything*? Here goes: Jan 1, 1262 Peasant in Germany eats breakfast. March 2, 1987. Ronald Reagan wears black shoes. Sept. 23, 1887. Three businessmen meet in restaurant in NY... If you mean *everything*, well, I brushed my teeth today, hit snooze on my alarm clock, ate breakfast, and much more besides. BTW, what's wrong with Wikipedia. I'm pretty sure it's the largest English Encyclopedia. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Size_comparisons

Comment: There is nothing wrong with Wikipedia, but it provides no automated way to query it's contents, and by contents I mean 'historical facts'. I should have specified that I wanted facts considered important, not tweets and facebook updates.

Comment: @ivanhoe1982, this question would be more appropriate in another area that deals with APIs and programming in general. I am going to move it.

Comment: @StevenDrennon unfortunately, this isn't a good fit for SO either. I expect it to be closed as off topic.

Comment: @jrummel Is there any place on this network of websites to ask this question then? :)

Comment: I'm not sure. The only site I frequent is SO, and I see a lot of these kinds of questions closed.

Comment: This would be an interesting project. I'd love to work on it.

Comment: @JimBlizard Sure, catch me on ivanhoe1982 at gmail

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The closest thing is Wikipedia. The answer is No.

EDIT: These are a few I have found since asking this question:

```
http://thebigdb.com/

http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Main_page
```

EDIT2:  http://gdeltproject.org/ - Global Database Of Events

Comment: You should create one, I would use it, and possibly pay $10 per month for access.

Comment: I'm up for it. I have a database for my little iPhone app (the one I inconspicuously mentioned in the question - "history surfer"), and - since noone seems to run a db like that - I was thinking of building a community driven 'timeline of history' site.  I'm having trouble assessing the real market for it though.

Comment: @ivanhoe1982 , how is the time line of history site coming along?

Comment: not at all, but the little app is on the app store - "history surfer"